# How to create a static web project in IntelliJ Idea 13?

Tags: web, intellij-idea, webstorm

I would like to use IntelliJ Idea 13 (community edition preferably, but I would also like to know if this is only available in the professional edition) instead of WebStorm. The answer (written by a JetBrains official as far as I understand) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827214/can-intellij-idea-encapsulate-all-of-the-functionality-of-webstorm-and-phpstorm) sound like it is possible, it says (if I understand it right) all the functionality of Idea derivatives like WebStorm is is available in Idea plug-ins. But I still can't find the right plug-in to create static (HTML+CSS+JS code, no Java) web projects. If I try to open a WebStorm project Idea says it doesn't understand "WEB_MODULE" module type. What do I have to I set-up?

Comment: I think this documentation means Idea Ultimate. CE version lacks editor support for any of HTML/CSS/JS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Andrey mentioned, HTML+CSS+JS support is only provided in Idea Ultimate. No additional plugins have to be installed (unless you need Vue.js support or like to use *Live Edit* - these plugins, along with some others, are not bundled with Idea and have to be installed from the repository (**Preferences | Plugins**))

Comment: In the latest IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.1, entries named 'Static Web' in the **File | New | Project..** dialog were renamed to 'JavaScript'. For generic static Web projects, you need to select a new JavaScript project in this dialog.

Answer (score 31):

For those using IntelliJ IDEA 14.x.x Community Edition, the "Static Web" option in Projects or Modules only seems to show up after the `Phonegap/Cordova Plugin` has been installed (`Settings->Plugins->Browse repositories`).

Comment: Confirmed to work with IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4 (Community Edition) - thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 7):

- IDEA 12 Ultimate: "New Project" -> "Web Module"
- IDEA 13 Ultimate: "New Project" -> "Static Web"
- IDEA 14 Ultimate: "New Project" -> "Static Web"

[image: Screenshot of New Project > Static Web dialog box]

Answer (score 4):

### IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.1

Entries named 'Static Web' in the **File | New | Project..** dialog were renamed to 'JavaScript'.

For generic static Web projects, you need to select a new JavaScript project in this dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As alexbk said for 15.x.x it remains the same. You also have to install `Phonegap/Cordova Plugin` in (`Settings->Plugins->Browse repositories`) and restarting Intellij IDEA afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

## IntelliJ 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition)

The commercial version of [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition) offers a project template for HTML sites.

In the *New Project* dialog box, choose *HTML*. The fields of that dialog box [are documented](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.1/new-project-wizard.html#html).

For *Project type*, choose *HTML5 Boilerplate* for a plain web site. Choose the option *Bootstrap* if you want to take advantage of the [*Bootstrap* front-end framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(front-end_framework)). The *Version* number is the version of the templates generated by IntelliJ when creating your new project. See [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.1/new-project-wizard.html#html).

[image: screen shot of IntelliJ 2023.1 Ultimate Edition dialog box for New Project > HTML]

The resulting new project is a rather robust starter web site. Details even include a [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) file and a [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) file.

[image: screenshot of new web site project created by IntelliJ]

For a simple static site, you can strip out all the JavaScript, and replace the CSS with your own.