# How to Install Webstorm with IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ 13.1 Ultimate, I can't figure out how to install/use Webstorm.

Please note that I read the answer to this post- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13829907/409976, however I don't see "Webstorm" when searching:

[image]

Please tell me how to install Webstorm.

Comment: you don't need to...you doing php (poor you) ? just install php plugin.

Comment: oh? I'm using AngularJS

Comment: You should be able to just install the AngularJS plugin then.  Webstorm and IntelliJ IDEA are different (but similar) programs.

Comment: Hi @Makoto, when you say "install the AngularJS plugin," is there a list of official Webstorm plugins for Angular? Perhaps there's a list of Webstorm plug-ins that I can use in IDEA?

Comment: There should be an Angular plugin in the plugin search dialog (it's in the repository, not from the local machine).