# What plugins do I need to install to get WebStorm functionality in IDEA?

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-13

My company (Java + AngularJS shop) is evaluating both IDEA and WebStorm. Based on some Googling, it looks like IntelliJ IDEA is a superset of the *Storm editors, assuming you install the proper plugins ([source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827214/can-intellij-idea-encapsulate-all-of-the-functionality-of-webstorm-and-phpstorm), [source2](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5499611#5499611)):

Practically, if we purchased IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 Ultimate, what plugins would we need to get these WebStorm features?

- Grunt integration
- AngularJS integration
- Bower integration
- Karma integration
- JavaScript auto-complete/navigation

Comment: I also have similar question for plugin usage in phpstorm? Is there any list to figure out official installed plugins in phpstorm or other product? ( So I can buy one Idea, and then install it one by one or all?)

Answer (score 3):

Grunt and Bower support, as well as javaScript completion, etc. are available out of the box. AngularJS, Node.js and Karma plugins have to be installed from the repository (Settings/Plugins, Browse Repositories..., type plugin name in the search box to quickly locate it).

Answer (score 1):

Just search the [repo](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/?idea), you can do this from within intellij with a nice gui aswell.

javascript code complete is in vanilla (not an external plugin) version btw, as I would imagine most of the others are. Just try the trial version.