# % of code in GitHub is really wrong

Tags: git, github

Look at this two pictures (screenshots of my github's repository):

The first one is the percentage that appears in my first view of my repository.. 
[image: first view]

The second one is the really programming languages that I'm using. As you know you can go inside your projects and can see how many files of the different programming languages have.  I'm only using 58 files of css (you can't see it because is selected.. but only 58 files)

[image: inside view]

Does anybody have any idea why GitHub is doing this awesome thing?

Comment: This question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow. I'd contact GitHub for questions regarding their service. Stack Overflow isn't really meant to answer questions regarding specific service behavior.

Comment: @CharlieFish I disagree. There are countless questions on specific service behavior. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827214/can-intellij-idea-encapsulate-all-of-the-functionality-of-webstorm-and-phpstorm compares the differences between two offerings from JetBrains. Because that question asks about a service related to a certain application as thus this one, it is a valid question.

Comment: @Khagay Not sure if a similar question asked 4 years ago automatically means this question follows the guidelines and is valid as the guidelines and rules of this site have changed and evolved over time. As well that question is comparing two services. Not asking about specific behavior within a service. Also it's not really a programming specific question. [This question on Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156029/how-does-github-calculate-language-percentage-in-a-repo) is also the same question. A bit more research before posting is a good idea.

Comment: @CharlieFish it's comparing the two services by asking for the specific behavior of it... How would you compare two services without talking about their behaviors?For example, how would you compare Java and C++ by not talking about what each does.

Comment: @Khagay I never said the question you posted follows the current guidelines. But again it was posted 4 years ago. The Stack Overflow guidelines have evolved since then. All I'm saying is these type of questions you are more likely to get a much better response from GitHub then on Stack Overflow as they built the system and know exactly how it works (unlike users on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Sorry @Charlie Fish, probably you're right, but I think that Stack Overflow user's know a lot of things about github so I strongly believe that It's the best place that I could post my question.

Comment: @AAg Although Stack Overflow user's might know a lot about GitHub user's will never know as much as the developers of the software. Their support team will probably be able to give you the best answer. Again tho [check out this question](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156029/how-does-github-calculate-language-percentage-in-a-repo). Might not be as good of an answer as GitHub would be able to give you but defiantly a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem, I create a `/docs` folder in the root of my Github project in order to put there all of my folders of documentation, landing page... etc. And that solve my problem. I **don't know why** but this fix my problem.