# IntelliJ and React which IDE/Texteditor should I choose

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am going to develop a web application with React and want know which IDE/Text Editor would fit best.

IntelliJ IDEA for example supports the framework as well as WebStorm. And now I want to know if there are differences between the support of the editors as well as the benefits for implementing with one of these 2 IDEs.

As I am familiar with IDEA I would use it, if there is no important or nice feature missing compared to WebStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebStorms features are a subset of IntelliJ IDEAs. You won't miss any that might come with WebStorm and AFAIK IntelliJ will always ship new features (updates) at the same time (or even before) WebStorm.

Further reading:

[Can IntelliJ IDEA encapsulate all of the functionality of Webstorm and PHPStorm through plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827214/can-intellij-idea-encapsulate-all-of-the-functionality-of-webstorm-and-phpstorm/13829907#13829907)

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207461065-IntelliJ-Idea-Ultimate-vs-WebStorm

Comment: No problem. Might be a duplicate but it is also an answer from the year 2017 :)