# What are the roles of WebStorm and IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, frontend, webstorm, backend, jetbrains-ide

I want to create a web (frontend and backend) and I want to use JetBrains. Should I use WebStorm for frontend and IntelliJ for backend? Or should I have the whole code in just one IDE, and which one would that be?

I still don't understand how to use them properly, how the code of a website would be divided in the different IDEs.

Comment: JetBrains is a company, but IIRC IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate contains all functionality of Webstorm. IIRC.

Comment: Still JetBrains owns Webstorm as it appears as one of its IDEs in their official webpage.

Comment: I have used their database tool, DataGrip, and it is a standalone tool if all you're doing is databases. But all the functionality/UI of DataGrip is also available within PyCharm when you are doing a Python project with a DB. I think WebStorm is the same - if you're doing a Node/only JavaScript project WebStorm would be fine. But if you're planning a Java backend, with JS front, you could do everything in IntelliJ.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13829907/104891.